# How to add custom content in sidebar of each Wordpress post?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, sidebar

I want to integrate specific text (text, links, images) making reference to specific sentences of my blog post.

Is it possible to do it with code or using a plugin ?

I send you a sketch :
[This is the sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWmC8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is common need and often Aside in WordPress is talked for it. There are WP plugins like Aside Widget, Custom Sidebars for ordinary needs. But if you need too much custom stuff like my website's "About this Article" sidebar widget - https://thecustomizewindows.com/2016/09/limitations-of-openvz-virtualization-to-guest-cloud-server-vps/ then it is better to use 
Otto's this plugin to use PHP in text widget - https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-code-widget/ and use PHP. In my case, rest is PHP code like this on sidebar (I can use shortcode too) :

```
    <?php if(is_single()) : ?>
    <h3>About This Article</h3>
    <strong>Title:</strong> <?php echo get_the_title(); ?><br />
    Published on: <?php the_time('Y-m-d') ?>
    <br />
    ...
    // rest of the code
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Obviously you can call post image thumbnail with WordPress function.

As you need specific text, you may think about combining Pull Quote Plugin or Aside Widget to mark the specific like and echo it with PHP.

As other options -- you can use CSS3 to automatically select first line, first paragraph, second sentence. You can use Javascript to conditionally mark.

Best possible customisation I saw is on BMJ's sidebars. They use Drupal, not WordPress. BMJ has beautiful sidebar -- (as example) - http://www.bmj.com/content/355/bmj.i4924 Drupal has description of the work - https://www.drupal.org/node/1557636 Sadly I lack idea about Drupal. I tried a lot behind using WordPress for academic purpose.

Comment: Hello Abishnek Gosh,
This is a good begining :)

But I was thinking about for example a selectable sentence from the back office where the redactor can add specific content attached on the sidebar.

Comment: I have an example like that : http://lesjours.fr/obsessions/entreprise-terroriste/ep10-daoudi-perquisition/

Comment: My goodness! Your idea is just great. May be this http://www.codeandmore.com/products/wordpress-plugins/wp-page-widget/ plus this https://github.com/dfmcphee/wp-redactor-js

Comment: In short -- Mouse over on text will fetch the post to give a preview of text with image like Stock Market Data.

Comment: Thank you for the plugin I'll watch this. The second link is not found at home :/

Comment: I guess it will be easier to store data in separate database and fetch with qTip2 -- http://jsfiddle.net/qTip2/zok1Lyzo/

Comment: Good idea, may I have to call the attached content in js in the sidebar ?

Comment: This is closest to what you want. It renders "tool tips" on separate div - http://www.webappers.com/demo/json-tooltip/ I saw that WordPress actually has lot of plugins for plain tool tips -- https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-glossary-plugins/ So if you simply edit one such plugin with that jQuery, it should work great.

Comment: Thank you Abhishek :)
I think I'll use WP-Page-Widget + custom CSS/JQuery :)

Comment: You are welcome mate ! I am also testing the effect :)